# Why can't I set my Django Model's USPhoneNumberField to null=True, blank=True?

Tags: python, django, django-localflavor

My Django Model:

```
from localflavor.us.forms import USPhoneNumberField

class Profile(models.Model):
    cellPhone = USPhoneNumberField(null=True, blank=True,)
```

This gives me the following error when I do a manage.py syncdb:

```
cellPhone = USPhoneNumberField(null=True, blank=True,)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'null'
```

How can I make this field optional if it won't let me declare it as null=True like I do for so many other fields?

Comment: Noise alert - here is  the link to [source code](https://github.com/django/django-localflavor/blob/master/localflavor/us/forms.py#L42-L45)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`USPhoneNumberField` is a `form` type, not a model type

The usage (typically) is:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    cellPhone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True,)
```

and forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.Form): #or forms.ModelForm
    cellPhone = forms.USPhoneNumberField(...)
```

Here is the [documentation](https://django-localflavor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/localflavor/us/#module-localflavor.us.models)

> class localflavor.us.models.PhoneNumberField(*args, **kwargs)
>       A CharField that checks that the value is a valid U.S.A.-style phone number (in the format XXX-XXX-XXXX).